# Reading a text file line by line in c

Tags: c

I try to read the file that I wrote the first three line, line by line. However, it enters infinity loop. How can I stop it at the end of the file?

```
while(fscanf(infile, "%[^\n]", ch) != EOF)
   printf("%s", ch);


Tiffany;Evans Smith;F;22/01/1989;
Alex;Williams;M;23/06/1988;
Clay;Bristol;F;30/12/1989;
```

Comment: `"%[^\n]"` --> `"%[^\n]%*c"` : You need to consume newlines.

Comment: You could use `fgets` which includes the newline in the text. Comparing `fscanf` with `EOF` can stall, as you have discovered.

Comment: In standard C, use [`fget()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fget.html); under POSIX, consider using [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) which alloctes enough space if the line is much longer than you expected.  And I'd be surprised if this is not a duplicate of other questions, but the problem will be finding the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of reading a text file line by line. Hopefully, the following code answers your question.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>

 int main()
 {
   FILE *infile;
   char data[BUFSIZ];

   infile=fopen("filename","r");

   while((fgets(data,BUFSIZ,infile)!=NULL))

  puts(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use fscanf, you can use this code :

```
int ret;        
while(ret = fscanf(infile,"%s",str))
{
    if (ret == EOF)
        break;
    if(ret >0 )
    {
        cout << str <<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

here, int ret is:

- EOF, if the pointer is reached end of file.
- 0, if no input matched with the variable
- >0, number of matched variables with the file input